# How to update backbone model from database

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-model

I am creating a webpage to show the listing from my database table,
suppose my database table is updating in every 10 second from my php cron , then i want to sync my backbone model/collection whenever my database table get update from my php cron.

Example:- i have table stock_exchange in which i am storing the stocks rate for various companies, and my cronjob update the stocks rate in every 10 second, To show this on UI i am creating the backbone application but my problem is that whenever my table stock_exchange updated i want to sync my backbone model/collection.

Please help, 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can either poll the server by calling `stockModel.fetch()` every 10 seconds in the browser (via `setInterval` perhaps), or you can use something like web sockets (via socket.io perhaps) to allow the server to push the latest data to the browser, which you can then do `stockModel.set(dataFromServer);`. Try something and post some code as stack overflow is intended for specific problems not tutorials.